# Is database is in backup mode?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-backups

Is there any way to find whether the database is in backup mode or not.
Is any sys tables can provided this informtion.

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to a Recovery model in *SQL SERVER* ?
if so, the query is:

**select name, database_id, recovery_model_desc from sys.databases**

if you are referring to *Oracle database*, and you're asking how to check whether the database is in backup mode (after issuing 'alter database BEGIN BACKUP'), then the query is:

**select * from v$backup;**

if one of the rows return with ACTIVE in the status column, then one of the tablespaces is in backup mode.

Comment: Thanks Roni, i used ur ys.databases table along with backupset and got the required qry : 
i am only in need which database is not taking part in Backup process. here its begins : 
select * from sys.databases where name not in (select database_name from backupset);